# How to disable isolated/partitioned resources (and service workers) from cross origin Iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I'm building a fully client side web development environment which hosted in separate domain, one is the code editor and the other one is for previewing the code.

[image]

The communication works by registering and sharing `MessageChannel` port to previewer's service worker by opening `preview-example.com` on an iframe element in `editor-example.com`. This way, my app can automatically establish a connection via service worker even if the `preview-example.com` tab is closed or yet to be opened. I use `postMessage` to establish the initial connection.

Everthing works fine until I updated ChromeOS recently. I noticed that now I have 2 active service workers registered for `preview-example.com`, both registered for the same origin and same scope ...

[image]

... except that now the one opened inside an iframe has its own partitioned storage and presumably workers. Notice the (^) symbol for local storage domain. Hence my app can't reestablished the connection automatically.

[image]

My website works fine in current Chrome version on windows 10, so I'm guessing it has something to do with recent Chrome updates but I can't find any solid information on how to revert back or disable this default behaviour.

## Things I've Tried

Right now I have a workaround by sharing MessageChannel port directly to the service worker of newly opened `preview-example.com` tab/window. The limitation is that, because service worker seems to died after 10-20 seconds, my app need to manually reestablish the connection by reopening `preview-example.com` from `editor.com`.

I'm hosting my app on firebase.

### Response Header Settings

Based on information from below articles :

- https://chromeenterprise.google/intl/en_ca/policies/#OriginAgentClusterDefaultEnabled
- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-112-beta/
- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/anonymous-iframe-origin-trial/

firebase.json

```json
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "**",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Origin-Agent-Cluster",
          "value": "?0"
        },
        {
          "key": "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy",
          "value": "unsafe-none"
        },
        {
          "key": "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
          "value": "unsafe-none"
        },
        {
          "key": "Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy",
          "value": "cross-origin"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

No luck so far.

The storage and worker doesn't get partitioned when I tried serving the app through Github codespace (`localhost5000.example.com`, `localhost5005.example.com`).

Registering a sub domain or building browser extension is not an option right now.

My ChromeOS version where I encounter this issue :
Version 111.0.5563.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)